# SonarQube - Sonarway with findbugs , PMD and checkstyle plugin

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

Many projects in our company are already using sonarway with PMD and findbugs plugin.

1) We want to check the delta for sonarway(Java), PMD plugin and findbugs plugin what is the overlap.

2) What would be the best practice to use all the three plugins, with activating and deactivating few rules? or sonarway(java) alone is enough and has all the best practice and required rules that are also covered in find bugs and PMD plugin.

3) what is the best combination ruleset.

We are using SonarQuber 5.6.3.

Latest checkstyle requires an upgrade to 5.6.4 currently focusing on PMD, Findbugs and Sonarway plugin only.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually There is no such thing as best combination.

sonarway(java) alone is not enough they haven't yet integrated all the      rules in PMD,Checkstyle,Findbugs etc into sonarway.

And i will not suggest using all the rules in these plugins because some of them are really not that important.

Some rules might make no sense to you. Good examples are the Checkstyle JavadocMethod rule that verifies if each method has Javadoc comment or the PMD OnlyOneReturn rule that verifies if a method has only one exit point, and that it is the last statement in the method.

And incase of Android Lint all the official rules are not available in sonarqube,only 158 rules are present in sonarqube,but there are 281 rules in android-lint officially.

Whenever your team finds out such rule, discuss as a whole whether it is worth keeping it or dropping it. Many rules have some disadvantages and there is no sense in adjusting your code to them if the majority is against. Developers should identify themselves with the project and believe in it to achieve the best productivity. Doing things that they think doesn’t make sense will not motivate them.

This way you may be able create a best combination thats suits for you 
and your team,Hope it helps.